# How to create moq for property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

How do I write moq for an entity for the method given below,
especially for properties like `db.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.EffectiveDate).IsModified = true;`?

```
public bool UpdateEffectiveDate(int driverId, DateTime effectiveDate, string UserId)
{
    db myentity = new myentity();
    Driver driver = db.Drivers.Find(driverId);
    driver.EffectiveDate = effectiveDate;
    driver.LastModifiedBy = UserId;
    driver.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    db.Drivers.Attach(driver);
    db.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.EffectiveDate).IsModified = true;
    db.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.LastModifiedBy).IsModified = true;
    db.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.LastModifiedDate).IsModified = true;
    return (db.SaveChanges() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Isnt Moq for unit tests?

Comment: yes it is used for unit test

Comment: The unit test is where you will be mocking, can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your Method to use Method Injection.

```
public bool UpdateEffectiveDate(db aEntity, int driverId, DateTime effectiveDate, string UserId)
{
    //db myentity = new myentity();
    Driver driver = aEntity.Drivers.Find(driverId);
    driver.EffectiveDate = effectiveDate;
    driver.LastModifiedBy = UserId;
    driver.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    aEntity.Drivers.Attach(driver);
    aEntity.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.EffectiveDate).IsModified = true;
    aEntity.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.LastModifiedBy).IsModified = true;
    aEntity.Entry(driver).Property(x => x.LastModifiedDate).IsModified = true;
    return (aEntity.SaveChanges() > 0);
}
```

Then you setup your test like so...

```
  var _MockEntity = new Mock<db>();
  var _MockDrivers = new Mock<Drivers>();
  var _MockDriver = new Mock<Driver>();
  _MockEntity.Setup(x => x.Drivers()).Returns(() => _MockDrivers.Object);
  _MockDrivers.Setup(x => x.Find(123)).Returns(() => _MockDriver.Object); 
  _MockDriver.SetupProperty(x => x.EffectiveDate);
  _MockDriver.SetupProperty(x => x.LastModifiedBy);  
  _MockDriver.SetupProperty(x => x.LastModifiedDate); 

  myClass.UpdateEffectiveDate(_MockEntity.Object, 123, samedatehere,"test");
  var _Driver = _MockDriver.Object;
  var _Expected =  samedatehere;
  var _Actual =_Driver.EffectiveDate;
  Assert.Equal(_Expected, _Actual);
```

Almost everything you need to learn how to mock with moq https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: I am unable to set propery for effective date I am getting an exception like  "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Moq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: l => l.EffectiveDate "